# How i can add button with action in the settings bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see many answers that says you can not add button with action in the settings bundle, 
but i saw

**Nike + iPod** application do it and the action is opening url also they doing a action on the switch view when it is turned off/on

Comment: Some people get special permission to do special things when they're a big company with a popular product...

Comment: @Wain No, that's not it and is irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add button to settings.bundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356474/how-to-add-button-to-settings-bundle)

Answer (score 4):

This is all you need:

```
...
<key>cell</key>
<string>PSButtonCell</string>
<key>action</key>
<string>buttonCellClicked:</string>
...
```

This will make a button cell and send the `buttonCellClicked:` message on the preferences view controller.

Comment: Is this legal for apps in the store?

Comment: H2CO3 would you provide me with a sample code or link for such thing ?

Comment: @OmarFreewan The sample code is in the answer above. If you have a settings bundle, just create a normal cell, add what I wrote, implement the corresponding method and it'll work.

Comment: This link is quite helpful but I think this is all private framework stuff so YMMV: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Preferences_specifier_plist