# How can I store a list and clear it from the settings page on iOS?

Tags: ios

I need to be able to store a list of data (either strings or objects) that is remembered by my app after it's closed. The user also needs to be able to go into the settings page for the app and clear this data by pressing a button.

Everything I read about the settings in iOS suggests that the only things that can appear there are controls that expose a specific setting. Is it possible to add a button that clears a setting list or is this unsupported?

Edit: I've just realised this must be possible because Safari does it - see the "Clear History" button:
[image]

Comment: There seems to be a way... [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Comment: No, there isn't a way. You'll need an in-app Settings page.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen, have you tried? The more I read the more it seems to be possible. I've never done this before, but in [this example](http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/ios-how-to-create-an-ios-settings-entry-for-your-app-using-settings-bundle/) he seems to set a BOOL and checks the value in `NSUserDefaults`. As long as his app runs in the background, shouldn't he be able to check a similar value and set his data to `null`?

Comment: You can't add a button to Settings. The settings screen essentially maps 1-1 to settings bundle (that's why it can never contain a button, since a button cannot be mapped into a value, whatever type that value is). The best thing he can do is to add a Switch (flag) saying something like 'Clear XXX next time app starts', and then when the app goes foreground, check the flag, delete the list if the flag true, then set the Switch (flag) to false again; which is a clumsy pattern, and not what Settings page is supposed to be used for.

Comment: @parsley72 wrt the EDIT: It's iOS native stuffs. Apple do what they want. I have never seen something similar with an external app.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen, I see what you mean. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356474/how-to-add-button-to-settings-bundle) seems to be asking the same question.

Comment: You can add a button that sets a flag, then when the app starts check that flag and clear the settings if it's set.  (And don't forget to clear the flag as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.  You don't get to run code from the iOS Settings app.  Safari is special because Apple.

Your choices are two:

1. Have a toggle that the user can set to ON which is "Clear list on next launch".  Then when your app launches, you check to see if the user toggled that to ON, clear the list and reset it to OFF.
2. You have an in-app settings page where the user can click a button to clear the list immediately.